# php ajax returns some html content instead of numeric value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm getting the nominee_role value from **add_employee file**.

In **nominee_role** im getting 7000 as a result, but when I'm trying to get the **data** value in alert it returns some html contents.

```
<?php  
  include('database.php');
  include("header.php");
  include("left_side_bar.php");

 ?>
    <div class="row">
     <!-- left column -->
   <div class="col-xs-12">
     <div class="box box-primary">
    <div class="box-header">
    <h3 class="box-title">
    Add employee
    </h3>
    <?php
    extract($_POST);
//echo $name;

            $current_date=date("Y-m-d");
            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                //echo "hi";
                $select = "SELECT * FROM `emp_details` WHERE `branch_name` = '".$branch_code."' AND `emp_role` = '".$emp_role."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
                //echo $select;
                $exe_select=mysql_query($select);
                $fetch=mysql_fetch_array($exe_select);
                $rows = mysql_num_rows($exe_select);
                $emp_id ='0001';
                    if($rows == 0)
                    {
                        $emp_id ='0001';
                        $emp_code=$branch_code.$emp_role.$emp_id;
                        //echo "employee code: ".$emp_code;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $emp_id=$fetch['emp_code'];
                        echo $emp_id;
                        //exit();
                        $emp_id= $emp_id +1;
                        $emp_code=$emp_id;
                        //echo "employee code: ".$emp_code; 
                    }
                //exit();
                $sql="INSERT INTO `emp_details` 
                        (`emp_name`, `emp_code`, `emp_role`, `dob`, `age`, `address`, `contact_number`, `gender`, `pan`, `bank_acc`, `ifsc_code`, `branch_name`,`intro_code`, `nom_name`, `nom_address`, `nom_age`, `nom_gender`, `relationship_status`, `created_date`) 
                        VALUES 
                        ('".$name."', '".$emp_code."', '".$emp_role."', '".$dob."', '".$age."', '".$address."', '".$contact_num."', '".$gender."', '".$pan."', '".$acc_num."', '".$ifsccode."', '".$branch_code."', '".$intro_code."', '".$nom_name."', '".$nom_add."', '".$nom_age."', '".$nom_gender."', '".$rel_status."', '".$current_date."' )";
                        //print_r($sql);
                        //exit();
            $exe_query=mysql_query($sql);

            if($exe_query)
            {
                echo '<h3 class="msyqlsuccess">Employee Details Added Successfully</h3>';
            }
            else
            { 
                echo '<h3 class="msyqlerror">Employee Details Not Added</h3>'; }
            }
    ?>
    </div>
    </div>
               <!-- form start -->
    <form role="form"  method="post" class="agentdetails" id="add_agent_details" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <div class="box-body clearfix">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Employee Name" id="name" required="required" name="name" class="form-control" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>DOB</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter DOB" id="date_of_birth" required="required" name="dob" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Age</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Employee Age" id="age" required="required" name="age" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Address</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Employee Address" id="address" required="required" name="address" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Contact Number</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Contact Number" id="contact_num" required="address" name="contact_num" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Gender</label>
                <select name="gender" id="gender" class="select">
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Employee Role</label>
                <select name="emp_role" id="" class="select">
                     <option value="">---Select User Role---</option>
                     <option value="1000">Adviser</option>
                     <option value="2000">Agency Manager</option>
                     <option value="3000">Sales Manager</option> 
                     <option value="4000">Business Development Manager</option>
                     <option value="5000">Executive Manager</option>
                     <option value="6000">Senior Executive Manager</option>
                     <option value="7000">Director</option> 
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Branch Name</label>
              <select name="branch_code" id="" class="select">
                    <option value="">--Select Branch--</option>
                    <option value="130">Chennai</option>
                    <option value="150">Pondicherry</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>PAN Number</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter PAN" id="pan" required="required" name="pan" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Bank Account</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Bankacc" id="acc_num" required="required" name="acc_num" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>IFSC Code</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter IFSC Code" id="ifsccode" required="required" name="ifsccode" class="form-control" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Introducer Code</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Introducer Code" id="intro_code" required="required" name="intro_code" class="form-control" />
            </div>
           <div class="form-group">
                <label>Nominee Role</label>
                <select name="nominee_role" class="select nominee">
                     <option value="">---Select Nominee Role---</option>
                     <option value="1000">Adviser</option>
                     <option value="2000">Agency Manager</option>
                  <option value="3000">Sales Manager</option> 
                  <option value="4000">Business Development Manager</option>
                 <option value="5000">Executive Manager</option>
                     <option value="6000">Senior Executive Manager</option>
                     <option value="7000">Director</option> 
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Nominee Name</label>
               <select name="nom_name" id="" class="select nominee_name">
                     <option value="">---Select Nominee Role---</option>

           <?php

                       echo $nominee_role = $_POST['nominee_role'];
                       //echo "hi";
              //load nominee name
               $get_nominee="SELECT * FROM `emp_details` WHERE `nom_role` =    '".$nominee_role."'";
             echo $get_nominee;
              $exe_nominee=mysql_query($get_nominee);
              $is_nominee=mysql_fetch_array($exe_nominee);

         $nominee_row=mysql_num_rows($exe_nominee);
              if($is_nominee)
               {
                      echo  '<option value="'.$is_nominee['emp_code'].'">'.$is_nominee['nom_name'].'</option>';

              }
              else
              {

                  echo  '<option value="">No names are found</option>';  

              }
            ?>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Nominee Age</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Nominee Age" id="nom_age" required="required" name="nom_age" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Nominee Address</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Nominee Address" id="nom_add" required="required" name="nom_add" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Nominee Gender</label>
                <select name="nom_gender" id="" class="select">
                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Relationship Status</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Relationship Status" id="rel_status" required="required" name="rel_status" class="form-control" />
            </div>

           <div class="box-footer">
                     <?php //if($num){ ?>
 <!--                          <button class="btn btn-primary" id="next" value="Update" type="submit" name="submit" style="margin-top: 6%;">Update</button>
 -->                          <?php //} else { ?>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary submit" id="add_agent_details" value="Submit" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
                    <?php //} ?>
          </div>  
         </div>

    </form>

</div>

</div>




 <?php

 include("footer.php");
 die;
 ?>


<script>
    $('.nominee').change(function () {
        var nominee_role = $('.nominee').val();
        alert(nominee_role); // '7000'
        //send nominee role
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "add_employee.php",
            data: {nomi_role: nominee_role},
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Kindly help me to solve this! I really don't know where I leave a mistake!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66564/discussion-on-question-by-keerthi-php-ajax-returns-some-html-content-instead-of).

Answer (score 0):

Add `die;` at the end of add_employee.php file;

Comment: sorry..I cannot get any changes:(

Comment: </div>
    
    </div>
 
 
 

<?php

include("footer.php");
die;
?>

Comment: remove html content from `your file`

Comment: @keerthi you dont need to include footer.php in ajax called php file remove it just echo value you want in return on add_employee.php

Comment: im having form in that file...how do i remove html content

Comment: can You please elaborate it by showing the code @keerthi

Comment: @ user3782114 in footer file i have included all my js files

Answer (score 0):

while you didnt include your `add_employee file`  then lets say you have this in that file.

```
     $your_var = 7000 ;
     $other_value = 8000 ;
  echo json_encode(array("val"=>$your_var , "val2"=>$other_value ));
```

then in your ajax you should have this :

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add_employee.php",
        data: {nomi_role: nominee_role},
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.val); //will give you 7000.
            alert(data.val2); //will give you 8000.

        }
    });
```

Hope that helps .